# select distinct items from a column in powershell

Tags: powershell, distinct-values

If I issue following command in PowerShell, I get a lot of rows back.

```
PS C:\Users\benh> get-command

CommandType     Name                               ModuleName                         Definition
-----------     ----                               ----------                         ----------
Cmdlet          Get-Variable                       Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility       Get-Variable...
Cmdlet          Get-WebAppDomain                   WebAdministration                  Get-WebAppDomain...
Cmdlet          Get-WebApplication                 WebAdministration                  Get-WebApplication...
Cmdlet          Get-WebAppPoolState                WebAdministration                  Get-WebAppPoolState...
...
Cmdlet          Get-WinEvent                       Microsoft.PowerShell.Diagnostics   Get-WinEvent...
Cmdlet          Get-WmiObject                      Microsoft.PowerShell.Management    Get-WmiObject...
Cmdlet          Get-WSManCredSSP                   Microsoft.WSMan.Management         Get-WSManCredSSP...
Cmdlet          Get-WSManInstance                  Microsoft.WSMan.Management         Get-WSManInstance...
Cmdlet          Group-Object                       Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility       Group-Object...
Cmdlet          Import-Alias                       Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility       Import-Alias...
Cmdlet          Import-Clixml                      Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility       Import-Clixml...
Cmdlet          Import-Counter                     Microsoft.PowerShell.Diagnostics   Import-Counter...
Cmdlet          Import-Csv                         Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility       Import-Csv...
Cmdlet          Import-LocalizedData               Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility       Import-LocalizedData...
Cmdlet          Import-Module                      Microsoft.PowerShell.Core          ...
```

What I *want* to do is get all the distinct ModuleNames returned by Get-Command. How can I do this with PowerShell?

In pseudo-C#:

```
PowerShell.Exec("Get-Command").Select(a=> a.ModuleName).Distinct();
```

Comment: Not really what you asked, but consider using "Get-Module" instead.

Answer (score 97, accepted):

Have you tried something like this?

```
get-command | select ModuleName | sort-object -Property ModuleName -Unique
```

Comment: Plain old *select* was exactly what I was looking for, thanks!

Comment: +1 as this solution is case insensitive, Ex, getting AD computer names and DNS records and trying to show only unique names when the capitalization might be different.

Comment: I'm new to PS. Can you explain why the sort-object is needed? I was attempting to do "| select -unique"

Answer (score 69):

Even shorter:

```
get-command | select-object  moduleName -unique
```

Comment: Fyi, this is case sensitive, for case insensitive use `Sort-Object -unique` like in [srgerg's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8439487/101679). [Reference](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2012/01/15/use-powershell-to-choose-unique-objects-from-a-sorted-list/)

Comment: Good to know that -unique in Select-object is case-sensitive.  Are module names case sensitive, though?  Is it possible to have 2 modules loaded where the only difference is in case?

Comment: I don't think so, this would be more relevant to the title of the question vs the specific use case of the asker.

Answer (score 7):

Below 2 commands will bring out same result, but the first one will be sorted and a bit expensive in execution time.

The execution time will be taken more into consideration when you have large number of items, For example if you are importing `csv` file of 30,000 rows. Then second option will be faster, and once you get unique values sort them if you need because here sorting will be done on a much lesser number of items hence better performance.

1.

```
get-command | select ModuleName | sort-object -Property ModuleName -Unique

# This will give you the execution time
Measure-Command {get-command | select ModuleName | sort-object -Property ModuleName -Unique}
```

2.

```
get-command | select ModuleName -Unique

# This will give you the execution time
Measure-Command {get-command | select ModuleName -Unique}
```

Answer (score 5):

Another option:

```
Get-Command | Group-Object ModuleName -NoElement | Select-Object Name
```